# Laravel Backpack showing popup for unlicensed software

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I have been using Laravel backpack 4.1 for over 2 years and deployed on a live server.
Today I noticed that in my .env APP_DEBUG was always set to true. So for security purposes, I changed it to false. After doing so, I started getting the following popup:

"You're using unlicensed software. Please ask your web developer to purchase a license code to hide this message."

I have never faced this issue before. I have deployed many Laravel projects that are using backpack 4.1 and never got this popup until I changed the app_debug to false.

Did the app_debug trigger that popup?

Answer (score 2):

Backpack 4.1 had a YUMMY License (YoU make Money, I make MoneY) https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/4.1/LICENSE.md

That means that if you make money using Backpack (sell your projects to your clients etc) you should be getting a license for those projects. Otherwise you could apply for a free licence.

We don't want to bother developers while project is on development (app_debug and env) so that notice is not shown, but when they move to production they should either ask for a free license if they are not making money out of it, or buy a license in case they do.

Having `app_debug => true` in a production server is **A VERY HIGH SECURITY RISK**.

We now had to switch to an Open-Core in v5, because like you said .. you deployed ALOT of projects without paying a cent (you are not the only one, so don't take this personal), we have now an OPEN-SOURCE core (backpack/crud) and the paid features backpack/pro, backpack/editable-columns, backpack-devtools etc.

Again please, don't take this personal, we know this had been done by alot of people and I am not condemning, we just switched our business model.

Thanks, and if you consider buying a license, thanks again in advance! :-)